# How to delete record from installation table of parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

My code is as below:

```
public static void insertObjectIdInIinstallation(){
            ParseInstallation installation =ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
            installation.put(Constants.USER,ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
        }

//cannot update the installation table object id    

ParseInstallation installation =ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
            installation.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.d("error", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

I want to delete record from parse table. And also i can't delete the row which I have inserted at the time of application installation.

Comment: do you want to delete the entire record ?

Comment: yes i want to delete whole record

Comment: when you use the above code what problem you are facing?